# no HDMI, how to connect via arduino

Tags: hardware, serial, arduino, operating-systems

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 but no HDMI cable but I do have a 2560 mega Arduino.
I read a couple of places that Arduino has an onboard ttl chip.

on the Arduino I shorted reset to gnd (which should of put it into the proper mode)
I connect tx1/rx0 on the arduino with pin 8 and 10 on the Pi
https://pinout.xyz/#
then ground to gnd and 5.5v to pin 4

when I set minicom to /dev/ttyAMC0  (the same device that appears in Arduino normal mode), minicom just locks up.

[http://imgur.com/a/TGiwc](https://imgur.com/a/TGiwc)

How do I connect to a Raspberry Pi via rs232 using Arduino as a serial to USB bridge on Linux?

UPDATE:
Note:  http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/using-arduino-as-a-bridge-to-connect-serial-devices-with-pc

the Pi 3 appears to be DOA. I found HDMI and get a black screen upon power on.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that couldn't be done via SSH or VNC? You also run the risk of destroying your Pi since the GPIO pins are not 5 volt tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

To do so you need to enable serial console on RaspberryPi-hosted OS - it's not hardware-only feature. For bootscreen it's a line `enable_uart=1` at the **end** of `/boot/config.txt`, for your OS distribution refer to it's docs